# How to cross-reference to a specific label with RefTeX

Tags: cross-referencing, emacs, auctex, reftex

In LaTeX, the labels are defined as `\label{eq:1}`. When you want to reference to that equation, you could easily search all `\label`  in the document by `C-c )` and that command insert reference to that label `\ref{eq:1}`

Currently I am using a special language in which every labels are in the form `label{eq:1}` and the references `ref{eq:1}`(no backslash). So I wonder how I could customize RefTeX to search  `label` and insert `ref` for a chosen label.

Comment: Off-topic: You can use basically use anything in a label name, so `\label{thisisaverynicelabel}` or `\label{einstein was right}` would work too ;-) In fact, `\label{eq:1}` with numbers is not the preferred style to do so, as soon as the order of equations changes, the 1st equation might become the 3rd one, for example, but it is still labeled as `eq:1`

Comment: I am not using LaTeX but a special markup language (Doconce) requires `label{eq:1}` instead of `\label{eq:1}` in LaTEX. But I could use RefTeX for Doconce but RefTeX doesn't recognize `label{eq:1}`. RefTeX wants backslash in front of `label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RefTeX stores regexps matching `\label` definitions in `reftex-label-regexps`; you have to customize it in order to match `label` without a `\`.  You can make the `\` optional by putting it inside a shy group.

Then you have to write some code to run the functions `reftex-reference` and `reftex-label` with the second optional `NO-INSERT` argument and bind the functions to some key strokes.  Putting something like this in your `.emacs` should do the trick:

```lisp
(add-hook 'reftex-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            ;; do this all only once
            (unless (member
                     "\\(?:\\\\\\)?label{\\(?1:[^}]*\\)}"
                     reftex-label-regexps)
              ;; label stuff
              (setq reftex-label-regexps
                    '("\\(?:\\\\\\)?label{\\(?1:[^}]*\\)}"
                      "\\[[^][]\\{0,2000\\}\\<label[[:space:]]*=\[[:space:]]*\
{?\\(?1:[^],}]+\\)}?"))
              (reftex-compile-variables)
              (defun doconce-label ()
                (interactive)
                (insert "label{" (reftex-label nil t) "}"))
              (local-set-key (kbd "C-c l") #'doconce-label)
              ;; ref stuff
              (defun doconce-ref ()
                (interactive)
                (insert "ref{" (reftex-reference nil t) "}"))
              (local-set-key (kbd "C-c r") #'doconce-ref))))
```